# Keyup: add a value when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, keyup

So I am using Keyup to calculate a total of input fields. So far so good.
But now I want to do this:
if checkbox #a is checked, add 12 to total amount. If not, add 0.

I based my code on this: http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/1/

```
$(document).keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes
  var element1 = parseFloat($('#element1').val())  * 16.28 || 0; // get value of field and multiply by price
  var total = 0+element1
});
```

How can I add the value of a checked checkbox and substract it if people uncheck it. 
(Or even better: with a radiobutton?)
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/1079/ **<-- updated** (add 12 only if something is given, floatnumber)

btw: `input` is to be `<input/>` and not `<input></input>`

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes        
  var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val()); // get value of field
  var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val()); // convert it to a float
  var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());    
  $('#added').html(firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue); // add them and output it
});

$('#check').on('change', function () {
  var total = parseFloat($('#added').text()); // <-- update for float
  if (total) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          total = total + 12;
      } else {
          total = total - 12;
      }
      $('#added').text(total);
  }
})
```

Comment: Looks like it's working! Only problem is with comma's. Since I am working with prices I need to add 12.5; and in your code it is rounding up to 12

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
$(document).keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes
  var element1 = parseFloat($('#element1').val())  * 16.28 || 0; // get value of field and multiply by price
  var total = element1;
  if ($('#a').is(':checked')) {
    total = total + 12;
  }
});
```